# Start loader from another loader. Right or Wrong?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager

I have listview that is populated through CursorLoader. CursorLoader is created by LoaderManager.LoaderCallback's createLoader method. I have no problems with this. The problem is in that I want to start another task when listview population is completed and fill listviews with additional data.
My current solution is to start a another loader inside onLoadFinished method.

Is this right solution or it can be done in more elegant and efficient way? Could you give some advice, because I don't have much experience in android development.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need in the first place 2 calls to get data? what's the trigger to start the 2nd loader - is it some kind of list item click which reveals more data?

Comment: I can see that you would want to do this for only the visible items in your list-view. But if you load the additional data for all the items right after the initial list-data, then just do that in the same Loader, in one step.

Comment: @Sean The thing is that in first load I collect call logs, and in the second I collect additional info for each phone number, such like location

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston What if the colection of additional data is a bit time consuming, the user will have to wait pretty much time when all the data is loaded. Please, correct me if I understood you wrong.

Comment: @Azat, that's another reason :-).   
But yes, you can init or restart a Loader from onLoadFinished, if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading from `onLoadFinished` will working without a problem. I did something similar in a pet project I had. I loaded data from my own ContentProvider and from there loaded contacts data from the phone's Contact ContentProvider. Each entry in my db could reference multiple contacts so I had to load my item before I knew which contact info to load. I chained the init/restart LoaderManager call to when I first received my item data in `onLoadFinished`. It works just fine and I used the contact data as a list afterwards. Granted I didn't use this approach to load data into a view inside an existing list view item. I used the data inside its own list in a detail view for my item. It should still work with what you want to do, but it can get messy appending data to the views and whatnot, especially since the view "lifecycle" is outside your control.

A better approach, IMO, would be to code a custom CursorAdapter that would use an AsyncTask or AsyncQueryHandler to fetch the extra data as the views are being created. Make sure to cache the data for subsequent use as the list scrolls. This second approach has the benefit of being independent of the external/secondary loader. It encapsulates all the logic required to display the data you need which includes loading the missing parts. It keeps the view data and display logic cohesive, safely tucked away inside a reusable module.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so in your second approach there will be a new async task for each row in the list? If so, wouldn't it hit performance on low-end devices?

Comment: I mentioned AsyncTask as an example. If your loading task is relatively short (a couple of seconds) then it shouldn't be a problem. And, like I said before, cache the result so it won't need to be fetched every time the view gets scrolled by. If your tasks will require more time to finish or are executing longer operations you should consider using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). They offer a more efficient and controlled multi-threading solution and can be very useful to keep your threads in check.